# Module homomorphism surjective but not injective

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

It's a well-known exercise in commutative algebra to show that if an A-module endomorphism of a noetherian module M is surjective, it's also injective.

What are examples that the statement is wrong if we drop the Noetherian hypothesis?

Comment: In fact $M$ need only be finitely generated, not necessarily Noetherian

Comment: @user115654: Yes if $A$ is commutative. If $A$ is non commutative, the noetherian case still works, but not the f.g. case.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: That's interesting - the OP seems to be only interested in commutative rings, but this is a nice fact regardless

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest example is probably that of a countable dimensional $\Bbb F$ vector space $V$. Fix a basis $\{b_i\mid i\in \Bbb N\}$

There are two linear transformations which come in handy:

- the one given by $A(b_i)=b_{i+1}$
- the one given by $B(b_i)=b_{i-1}$ for $i>0$ and $B(b_0)=0$.

If you check these out, you should see that $BA=Id_V$, so $B$ is surjective, but since $B(b_0)=0$ it's clearly not injective.

While we're at it, you might as well notice that $A$ is necessarily injective, but it's clearly not surjective since no multiple of $b_0$ is in its image.

---

I'd also like to toss out that the exercise is fairly standard for noncommutative rings too :) Modules with this property are called [hopfian modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_object#Hopfian_and_cohopfian_modules), with the dual notion being "cohopfian" of course. The above example gives us both a nonHopfian an a noncoHopfian $\Bbb F$ module.

Comment: extremly complicated answer for a trivial question -1

Comment: Dear @ZlatanderZechpreller : I would like to see your version of an answer (if you have one.)

Comment: of course: just take the derivative $d/dx:C^\infty(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow C^\infty(\mathbf{R})$?

Comment: Dear @ZlatanderZechpreller If you consider it briefly, your example could be greatly simplified by just restricting it to polynomials, and then it is very nearly what I gave, except for scaling on each coordinate. This is indeed the other accessible example. Regards

Comment: greatly? Id think this would simply make it much more artifical.

Comment: Dear @ZlatanderZechpreller : You'll understand if you consider that more students have better exposure to linear transforms and polynomials, as opposed to smooth functions. Regards

Comment: I agree that these examples are basically the same, but I don't agree with what you said in the last paragraph: to understand the derivative example one just needs to know the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller Rather than downvoting correct answers you should add yours.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the Prüfer $p$-group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, which is artinian. If you quotient by the minimal nonzero subgroup, you get a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$. So you can define an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ which is surjective but not injective.

You could also use a free module of infinite rank, say $M=R^{\mathbb{N}}$, with base $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and define $f(e_n)=e_{n+1}$, then use again an isomorphism of the image with $M$.

Another, perhaps surprising, example, is that of a *finitely generated* module with the property. Consider a ring $R$ such that the free right $R$-module $R_R$ is isomorphic to $R\oplus R$. So, if $f\colon R\to R\oplus R$ is this isomorphism, $p\colon R\oplus R\to R$ is the projection on the first component and $i\colon R\to R\oplus R$ is the injection into the first component, we see that
$$
p\circ f\colon R\to R
$$
is surjective but not injective, while
$$
f^{-1}\circ i\colon R\to R
$$
is injective but not surjective.

The standard example of such a ring is $R=\operatorname{End}(V)$, where $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Rings where $R^m\cong R^n$ implies $m=n$ (for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$) are said to have *invariant basis number*. Every commutative ring has IBN, but noncommutative ones may not have this property. There are, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, examples of rings such that $R^m\cong R^n$ if and only if $m\equiv n\pmod{k}$.

Comment: extremly complicated answer for a trivial question -1

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller Do you *really* think they are complicated?

Comment: perhaps artificial would be a better word

Comment: @ZlatanderZechpreller Artificial? Prüfer groups are very basic tools in abelian group theory. The example of a ring without IBN is very basic too, and also important for showing that noncommutative ring theory is quite different than commutative ring theory.