# Looking for a surjective map which is not injective over an artinian module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I would like to know if there exists a surjective map $f : \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \to \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, which is not injective.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: When you write $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ do you mean localization at the prime ideal $(p)$? What kind of map is $f$ (in what category)?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a localization at the prime ideal $(p)$, and $f$ is in the category of modules over an ring. Thank you.  :-)

Comment: Both are rank one free modules over a dvr and thus surjective map must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Do you know if there exists surjective endomorphism $f$ over an artinian module $M$ which is not noetherian, such that $f$ is not injective ? Thank you,

Comment: For example take the injective hull $I$ of the residue field of your ring. Then multiplication by $p$ on $I$ is surjective, but has kernel the residue field.

Comment: If you are looking for a surjective non-injective endomorphism of a $\mathbb Z$-module, what about the $p^{\rm th}$ power map of the group of all complex $p$-power roots of unity?

Comment: No, il look for a surjective non-injective endomorphism of a artinian, module or $ \mathbb{Z} $ - module which is not noetherian. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As to user26857 comment, in this case any $\mathbb{Z}$ module homomorphism is automatically a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ homomorphism, so what I say stands. For John Brevik's comment, the set you describe is precisely the injective hull as I describe it.

Comment: @Albert007 : in an above comment you asked : "Do you know if there exists surjective endomorphism f over an artinian module M which is not noetherian, such that f is not injective ?". You can have a look to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628144/module-homomorphism-surjective-but-not-injective/628152#628152).