# $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that every surjective ring homomorphism $f:R\to R$ is injective, then is $R$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that every surjective ring homomorphism $f:R\to R$ is injective, then is $R$ a Noetherian ring ?

Comment: Can you give an example of a ring $R$ and a surjective homomorphism that is not injective?

Comment: See also [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628144/module-homomorphism-surjective-but-not-injective).

Comment: $R$ polynomials over a field, with differentiation?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik A ring of polynomials in indeterminates indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ : send $X_{i+1}$ to $X_i$ and $X_0$ to $0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama : I was asking the user..

Comment: @Praphulla Ah sorry, I thought you were expressing disbelief.  :)

Comment: @CaptainLama : That was my mistake as well.. I should have used better words.. :)  your example is a nice one..

Answer (score 12):

Here's a counterexample.  Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[2^{1/3},2^{1/9},2^{1/27},\dots]\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Then $R$ is not Noetherian, since the ideal $(2^{1/3},2^{1/9},2^{1/27},\dots)$ is not finitely generated.  But the only ring-homomorphism $f:R\to R$ is the identity.  Indeed, any such $f$ must be the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$, and then $f\left(2^{1/3^n}\right)$ must be $2^{1/3^n}$ for each $n$ since $2^{1/3^n}$ is the only $3^n$th root of $2$ in $R$.

---

More generally, any non-Noetherian subring $R$ of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ works.  Indeed, if $a\in R$, then it is a root of a nonzero polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients.  If $a\neq 0$, $p(x)$ can be taken to have nonzero constant term.  The constant term of $p(x)$ is then in the ideal generated by $a$, since $p(a)=0$ and every other term of $p(a)$ is in the ideal generated by $a$.  Thus every nontrivial ideal in $R$ contains a nonzero integer.  It follows that any homomorphism $f:R\to R$ must be injective.

(In fact, any homomorphism $f:R\to R$ must also be surjective: it must send roots of any $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to roots of $p(x)$, and there are only finitely many such roots.  An injection from a finite set to itself is surjective, so the image of $f$ must contain all the roots of $p(x)$ in $R$.)

Comment: A similar counterexample is the real algebraic integers. Here the only ring endomorphism being the identity has the same proof as for the reals.